# jQuery - Replacing partial text inside of a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, replacewith

I am trying to replace the first 5 letters in all links on that page that contain `#OFN#` in the first 5 letters of the link with an image to replace `#OFN#` text, but want to retain the rest of the link text.

Here's what I'm using so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:contains('#OFN#')").each(function() {
        var calSubject = $(this).text().substring(5);
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='/images/ofn_bullet.gif' width='10' height='10' style='width: 10px; height: 10px; border: none;' />" + calSubject);
    });
});
```

But this approach removes the `<a> tag` completely from the text.  How can I do this without removing the `<a> tags`

Here's an example HTML of the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="eventDisplay('980','4/18/2013')">#OFN# 2013 Midwest Regional Meeting</a>
```

I tried using `.children()` but that doesn't seem to work either.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $(this).replaceWith in this line you are replacing anchor tag instead of that you should replace text() of anchor tag .

Comment: Thanks, yeah I totally picked the wrong one there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the text nodes and update them instead. <kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eqbaQ/2/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:contains('#OFN#')").contents().each(function(){
        // skip if not a text node
        if (this.nodeType != 3) {
            return true;
        }
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.substr(5);
        $(this).before("<img src='/images/ofn_bullet.gif' width='10' height='10' style='width: 10px; height: 10px; border: none;' />");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're approach was the best, IMO.  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `replaceWith`. Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/MPTp7/

`replaceWith` will replace the element that it is invoked on, which explains the behavior that you described. By using `$.fn.html`, you are replacing everything *inside* of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `html` method to put the code inside the link instead of replacing it:

```
$(this).html("<img src='/images/ofn_bullet.gif' width='10' height='10' style='width: 10px; height: 10px; border: none;' />" + calSubject);
```

Comment: yep, just changed it to this and BAM!  PERFECT!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something slightly more verbose:

```
var regex = /^#0FN#/;
$("a").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), html = $this.html();
    if (regex.test(html)) {
        html.replace(/#0FN#/, "image stuff");
        $this.html(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks clearer to me :

```
<a href="#" class="ofn" onclick="eventDisplay('980','4/18/2013')">
    <span>2013 Midwest Regional Meeting</span>
</a>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.ofn').prepend('<img class="icon" src="/images/ofn_bullet.gif" />');
});
```

And

```
a.ofn .icon {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border: none; /* Actually i think you mean outline rather than border */
}
```

Unless you MUST do it the way you do it for some reasons you didn't ell us about.

You could also move the onlick from the a tag to the javascript if the parameters of eventDisplay are always the same.

Comment: I thought you use `border` for images, not `outline`

Comment: If your goal is to remove the blue frame around the picture, then i think it is outline and not border. Not 100% sure though, long time i didn't do that.